# How to render an xml file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, renderpartial

I am building a rails app to display test results for an application that is already written.
The application generates an xml file.  I would like to have rails read the xml file, it's associated xsl file and render an html partial.

I'm able to get it to render it as a file using <% render :file => 'file_path_not_in_views/file.xml' %> and the contents of the text of the xml file is displayed, but none of the styling is applied.

Thank you.
a